# abap nieconn_refused: Problem while recieving an answer from an external server

Tags: abap

I am trying to use my SAP system as a client and to communicate with an external server. The code is working fine except for this bit right here:

```
CALL METHOD go_client->receive
EXCEPTIONS
  http_communication_failure = 1
  http_invalid_state         = 2
  http_processing_failed     = 3
  OTHERS                     = 4.
IF sy-subrc <> 0.
CALL METHOD cl_http_client=>get_last_error(
  IMPORTING
    code    = g_subrc
    message = g_errortext ).

WRITE: / 'Error accured: ', g_errortext, 'with the code: ', g_subrc.
EXIT.
```

ENDIF.

This returns the error "http_communication_failure". I figured out that the detailed message is "Connect to openlibrary.org:80 failed: NIECONN_REFUSED(-10)", however after hours of searching I couldn't figure out how to solve the problem.

anybody can help?

Comment: Can you access any other website from the ABAP server? (if you're unsure, run the program RSDEMO_HTML_VIEWER and try http://www.google.com for instance)

Comment: Just tried it out, google.com works fine. If I try openlibrary.org it says "file not found". Can I fix that somehow?

Comment: I personally don't have this error, the home page of openlibrary.org is displayed correctly. Maybe a firewall issue, ask your SAP or network administrator.

Comment: Ok, I will check with him. Thank you!